# What is the best tactic for high scoring words in Spelltower?

Tags: spelltower

I have been playing Tower mode in Spelltower and have had middling success, as I'm not sure whether it is better to go for lots of short words, a few long words, trying to use as many tiles as possible, etc.

What is the best tactic for high scoring words and games in Spelltower?

Answer (score 3):

Seems that it is best to go for the long words. Check out [this article about a spelltower genius](http://www.ironicsans.com/2012/04/how_to_score_a_million_points_.html).

Comment: Welcome to Gaming Stack Exchange, and thank you for your contribution. However, given the sometimes transitory nature of the internet it's generally considered helpful to respond with more than merely a single URL in your answer. Consider expanding this answer with a brief summary of the article  you're linking to.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to a lot of strategies I've seen mentioned I sometimes hold off clearing entire rows using Q, X, Z, or J. My first impulse is to go for it, but I first look to see if I can get a long word that might clear another critical reregn without taking out the pink letter word. My highest scores is a little over 43000 points. I hate when the program crashes and I loose my high  record.

Answer (score -1):

Long words are best in Tower mode. I look for places to line up 'tion' endings then look for words to connect.